# Merge and sum related subsets in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have a multidimensional array containing a set of data for `sales` and a set of data for `rd_sales`. I need to merge and sum the related values between these two data sets.

```
[
    'sales' => [
        'brand'=> [
            3 => [
                'total_qty'=> 12.000,
                'total_amt'=> 336000.00
            ],
            4 => [
                'total_qty'=> 1.240,
                'total_amt'=> 24800.00
            ],
        ],
        'sales_value' => 360800
    ],
    'rdsales' => [
        'brand'=> [
            1 => [
                'total_qty'=> 3.000,
                'total_amt'=> 91500.00
            ],
            3 => [
                'total_qty'=> 0.020,
                'total_amt'=> 600.000
            ],
            4 => [
                'total_qty'=> 5.000,
                'total_amt'=> 100000.00
            ],
        ],
        'sales_value' => 192100
    ],    
]
```

In the above sample, the `brand` data in `1` of `sales` is not found in the `brand` data of `rd_sales`, so it merely needs to be transferred to the result.

As for `3` and `4`, these data sets are represented in both sets -- the corresponding values need to be summed and stored in the result array.

[image]

Desired result:

```
array (
  'sum_rdsales_sales' => 
  array (
    'brand' => 
    array (
      1 => 
      array (
        'total_qty' => 3.0,
        'total_amt' => 91500.0,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'total_qty' => 12.02,
        'total_amt' => 336600.0,
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'total_qty' => 6.24,
        'total_amt' => 124800.0,
      ),
    ),
    'sales_value' => 552900,
  ),
)
```

Comment: show how should look the final array

Comment: Thank you @RomanPerekhrest. I just added final array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach(used functions: `array_sum`, `array_column`):

```
$arr = [
    'sales' => ['brand'=> [
        3 => ['total_qty'=> 12.000, 'total_amt'=> 336000.00],
        4 => ['total_qty'=> 1.240, 'total_amt'=> 24800.00],
        ], 'sales_value' => 360800],
    'rdsales' => ['brand'=> [
        1 => ['total_qty'=> 3.000, 'total_amt'=> 91500.00],
        3 => ['total_qty'=> 0.020, 'total_amt'=> 600.000],
        4 => ['total_qty'=> 5.000, 'total_amt'=> 100000.00],
        ], 'sales_value' => 192100],    
];

$result = [];
$result['sum_rdsales_sales'] = [
    'brand' => [],
    'sales_value' => array_sum(array_column($arr, 'sales_value'))];

// `$prevalent_arr` is the array which has larger amount of elements
if ((count($arr['sales']['brand']) > count($arr['rdsales']['brand']))) {
    $prevalent_arr = $arr['sales']['brand'];
    $compared_arr = $arr['rdsales']['brand'];
} else {
    $prevalent_arr = $arr['rdsales']['brand'];
    $compared_arr = $arr['sales']['brand'];
}

foreach ($prevalent_arr as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($compared_arr[$k])) {        
        $result['sum_rdsales_sales']['brand'][$k]['total_qty'] = $prevalent_arr[$k]['total_qty'] + $compared_arr[$k]['total_qty'];
        $result['sum_rdsales_sales']['brand'][$k]['total_amt'] = $prevalent_arr[$k]['total_amt'] + $compared_arr[$k]['total_amt'];
    } else {
        $result['sum_rdsales_sales']['brand'][$k] = $prevalent_arr[$k];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [sum_rdsales_sales] => Array
        (
            [brand] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [total_qty] => 3
                            [total_amt] => 91500
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [total_qty] => 12.02
                            [total_amt] => 336600
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [total_qty] => 6.24
                            [total_amt] => 124800
                        )

                )

            [sales_value] => 552900
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank for your ideas I got help from this answer. According to my current question your answer is right but i have a situation where "sales" and "rdsales" having different keys like "sales" having one Key that is "1" and "rdsales" having one key that is "3". In that case solution will not work. But thanks for your replay. I got some idea and solve my issue. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone facing different different situation in my case.
Working code is

```
foreach($depots as $depot){
   $depotid = $depot['Depot']['id'];
   if(isset($reportData[$depotid])){
        $sales_value = 0;
    // brand merging and sum of total amount for sale and rdsales
    foreach($brands as $key=>$brand){
     if(isset($reportData[$depotid]['sales']['brand'][$key]) && isset($reportData[$depotid]['rdsales']['brand'][$key])){
      if(array_key_exists($key, $reportData[$depotid]['sales']['brand']) && array_key_exists($key, $reportData[$depotid]['rdsales']['brand'])){
       $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['brand'][$key]['total_qty'] = $reportData[$depotid]['sales']['brand'][$key]['total_qty']+ $reportData[$depotid]['rdsales']['brand'][$key]['total_qty']; 
       $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['brand'][$key]['total_amt'] = $reportData[$depotid]['sales']['brand'][$key]['total_amt']+ $reportData[$depotid]['rdsales']['brand'][$key]['total_amt'];
       $sales_value += $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['brand'][$key]['total_amt'];
      }
     }
     else{
      if(isset($reportData[$depotid]['sales']['brand'][$key])){
       if(array_key_exists($key, $reportData[$depotid]['sales']['brand'])){
        $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['brand'][$key]['total_qty'] = $reportData[$depotid]['sales']['brand'][$key]['total_qty'] ; 
        $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['brand'][$key]['total_amt'] = $reportData[$depotid]['sales']['brand'][$key]['total_amt'];
        $sales_value += $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['brand'][$key]['total_amt'];
       } 
      }
      if(isset($reportData[$depotid]['rdsales']['brand'][$key])){
       if(array_key_exists($key, $reportData[$depotid]['rdsales']['brand'])){
        $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['brand'][$key]['total_qty'] = $reportData[$depotid]['rdsales']['brand'][$key]['total_qty'] ; 
        $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['brand'][$key]['total_amt'] = $reportData[$depotid]['rdsales']['brand'][$key]['total_amt'];
        $sales_value += $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['brand'][$key]['total_amt'];
       }
      }
     }
    }
    // total sale and rdsales value for a depot
    $reportData[$depotid]['sale_redis_add']['sales_value']=$sales_value; 
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired result can be succinctly written with a set of nested loops.  Summing the related data points can be done in a single line usung the null coalescing operator.

The outer loop is implementing a yechnique called "array destructuring" to produce two variables from the associative elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eHutp))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['brand' => $items, 'sales_value' => $sv]) {
    foreach ($items as $id => $item) {
        $result['brand'][$id]['total_qty'] = ($result['brand'][$id]['total_qty'] ?? 0) + $item['total_qty'];
        $result['brand'][$id]['total_amt'] = ($result['brand'][$id]['total_amt'] ?? 0) + $item['total_amt'];
    }
    $result['sales_value'] = ($result['sales_value'] ?? 0) + $sv;
}
ksort($result['brand']);
$result = ['sum_rdsales_sales' => $result];
var_export($result);
```